# Profile service is not available in code in Page_Load within ASP.NET Web Projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-web-developer, asp.net

Profile that is used for ASP.NET Profile Service is not available in Page code behind files like in Page_Load.

It may be just a problem with Visual Studio installation/configuration, but as another problem, classes placed in App_Code in not seen in page codes. Even when I'm adding new ASP.NET folder to my project, "App_Code" is not available as an option.

I tested the entire scenario with ASP.NET Web Project and Empty ASP.NET Web Project. This problem does exists while creating ASP.NET Website.

Environment: Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate x64, ASP.NET 4.0, Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.

What may be the problem and how it can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Profiles only Work Out-of-the-Box with the Web Site Template.`

To use Profile in Web project you need to **apply a work-around** that is available **[here](http://weblogs.asp.net/joewrobel/archive/2008/02/03/web-profile-builder-for-web-application-projects.aspx)**.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WebProfileBuilder

http://weblogs.asp.net/joewrobel/archive/2008/02/03/web-profile-builder-for-web-application-projects.aspx

Comment: It doesn't work. May be because I'm running Visual Studio 2010 x64.

Comment: I read through comments and found a solution for my problem. Now it works! tnks!